# Jurdan/Gordan Set/Group what does it mean?

Tags: calculus, probability, terminology

I am not native English speaker so I may have made a mistake writing the word or in translation.

My teacher mentioned the term "Jurdan group/set" Or it could be Gordan
What does it mean and what is its formal term so I can look it up in wikipedia?

Note: He mentioned something like it has a finite space like y=x^2 or a circle and so on

Comment: [Jordan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_theorem_(symmetric_group)) ? In this case see [Camille Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Jordan)

Comment: But there was a long article about that in wikipedia

Comment: You are looking for a Jordan curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem